# redirect to list page after clicking on add button in JSF and html page

Tags: redirect, jsf

i want to know how can i do the same actions: adding object an redirect to list.
here my jsp add page :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="table-style.css" />
</h:head>

<h:body>

<center>
    <h2>Add New Customer</h2>
</center>

<h:form styleClass="add-fome">

    <h:panelGrid columns="">

            Name : 
            <h:inputText id="name" value="#{customer.name}" size="20"
            required="true" label="Name">
        </h:inputText>

        <h:message for="name" style="color:red" />

            Age : 
            <h:inputText id="age" value="#{customer.age}" size="20"
            required="true" label="Age">
        </h:inputText>

        <h:message for="age" style="color:red" />

            Address : 
            <h:inputTextarea id="address" value="#{customer.address}" cols="30"
            rows="10" required="true" label="Address">
        </h:inputTextarea>

        <h:message for="address" style="color:red" />

    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:commandButton value="Submit"  action="#{customer.addCustomer()}" />
    <h:link value="Customer List" outcome="default" />

</h:form>
```

List page is named default.html
In my bean here is the add methode that its working :

```
 public String addCustomer() {
    Customer cust = new Customer();
    cust.setName(getName());
    cust.setAddress(getAddress());
    cust.setAge(getAge());
    customerBo.addCustomer(cust);
    clearForm();
    return "";
  }
```

For thes list method :

```
public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
    return customerBo.findAllCustomer();
}
```

so how can we make the redirection just before adding the customer?
Thanks

Comment: also [omnifaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/) is a great utility API for JSF. `Faces.redirect()` could do it if you wanted to use this API